# AppLinks stopped launching app after going to production

Tags: android, applinks

We have our development and production server setup at completely different domain names. Ex: dev.something.com & completelydifferent.ca

I was able to setup App Links meta tags on our development environment and managed to get it working. These are the meta tags included in the web page

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1151434932217239" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://dev.something.com/path/to/item" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Some title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Some description" />

<meta property="al:android:url" content="myscheme://item?id=12" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="My App" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.mydomain.myapp" />
```

I was able to share the link to fb and directly open the android app when clicked from fb android app.

Later we pushed the code to live at completelydifferent.ca and then the FB android app stopped launching my app for links shared from both development and production.

Is there something happening behind the scenes in fb that if same app_id is used in different domains it somehow stops the App Link workflow? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is actually very inconsistent with their support of the App Links standard. As of last week (April 2015) their main Android app was the only app in their portfolio that still offered any support. Facebook for iOS and Messenger on both platforms all ignore App Links.

I haven't heard of issues with using the same app_id on multiple domain. Have you confirmed that the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) is showing what you expect?

Comment: The OG Debugger shows correct output, it even shows the al tags in the raw section. However I checked again this morning and the app links magically started to work again. I think you are right about facebook being inconsistent with their app links standards!